# How can I smoothen the line in Google Directions API?

Tags: flutter, google-directions-api, google-polyline, google-maps-flutter

I want to have smoother polylines displayed on the map.
[See the screenshot of sharp polyline.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsmpE.jpg)

I found that   "polylineQuality":"HIGH_QUALITY" is [available](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes_preferred/config_poly) in Routes Preferred API but not in Google Directions API I guess. Any ideas how to improve the polyline smoothness?

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class Routing {
  Future<List<LatLng>> getPolylinePoints(
      LatLng source, LatLng destination) async {
    String apiKey = "API_KEY";
    String polylineQuality = "HIGH_QUALITY";
    String baseUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";

    String url = "$baseUrl"
        "origin=${source.latitude},${source.longitude}&"
        "destination=${destination.latitude},${destination.longitude}&"
        "key=$apiKey&"
        "polylineQuality=$polylineQuality";

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var points = jsonData['routes'][0]['overview_polyline']['points'];
      return decodePolyline(points);
    } else {
      throw Exception("Failed to load directions");
    }
  }

  List<LatLng> decodePolyline(String polyline) {
    List<LatLng> points = [];
    int index = 0;
    int len = polyline.length;
    int lat = 0;
    int lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
      int b;
      int shift = 0;
      int result = 0;
      do {
        b = polyline.codeUnitAt(index++) - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
      } while (b >= 0x20);
      int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
      lat += dlat;

      shift = 0;
      result = 0;
      do {
        b = polyline.codeUnitAt(index++) - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
      } while (b >= 0x20);
      int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
      lng += dlng;

      LatLng p = LatLng((lat / 1E5).toDouble(), (lng / 1E5).toDouble());
      points.add(p);
    }

    return points;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use Routes API instead of the Directions API

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/migrate-routes-why) for Routes API states why you should migrate to Routes API. And it says that,

> *The Routes API provides improved performance for calculating
> directions, distance, and travel time, making it worthwhile to replace
> apps that currently use Directions API and Distance Matrix API. Most
> of the functionality of Routes API is backward compatible with both
> Directions API and Distance Matrix API.*

I'm assuming that you needed the `polylineQuality` for the Directions API because Routes preferred is [only available to select customers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes_preferred#:%7E:text=Routes%20Preferred%20API%20is%20currently%20available%20only%20to%20select%20customers.%20Contact%20sales%20to%20learn%20more.) and you need to Contact Sales to avail the feature you wanted.

But if you take a look at Routes API, it actually has the same `polylineQuality` field where you can specify the quality of the poyline as `HIGH_QUALITY` or `OVERVIEW`. Ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/config_trade_offs#example_setting_polyline_quality

You can use this field when using `computeRoutes` method of the Routes API. You can check out the reference documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/reference/rest/v2/TopLevel/computeRoutes#polylinequality

Here's a guide from the documentation on how to Get a Route using `computeRoutes`: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/compute_route_directions

With this, I think the Routes API should suffice with your use case.